# Rails Thinks Field is Nil When it Shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `Event` model which has a `start_date` and `end_date`.  I have a simple validation to make sure that the `end_date` is after the `start_date`, however, the validation keeps failing when a date field is not changed, but another field is updated.  In such cases, it interprets the fields are nil, even though in the trace, the record shows the proper field values.

```
# error
undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
app/models/event.rb:32:in `end_after_start'


# validation in event.rb
attr_accessible :end_date, :start_date    

validate :end_after_start

def end_after_start
  if end_date < start_date
    errors.add(:end_date, "must be after the start date")
  end    
end


# request parameters in trace
{"utf8"=>"✓",
  "_method"=>"put",
  "authenticity_token"=>"DD6rVimJxAJclO4IKfv69Txn8XkJZ4IpHZhh+cHOpg4=",
  "event"=>{"name"=>"Birthday",
  "start_date"=>"05/16/2013",
  "end_date"=>"05/31/2013", 
  "commit"=>"Submit",
  "id"=>"5"}


# _form     
<%= f.text_field :start_date, :value => (@event.start_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if @event.start_date.present?) %>
<%= f.text_field :end_date, :value => (@event.end_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if @event.end_date.present?) %>
```

Even though I see the `end_date` and `start_date` populated in the trace parameters, if I add `put start_date` (or end_date) in the `end_after_start` validation, it prints as nil to the console.

Comment: what the controller looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by installing the [american_date](https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date) gem.  It allows for my date field to be displayed as MM/DD/YYYY and validates and saves my date correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your form is formatting your dates as "mm/dd/yyyy" and the fields are being submitted to your application in that format as strings.

There is no implicit conversion of a string in that format to a DateTime so your `start_date` and `end_date` are ending up nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set:

```
attr_accessor :end_date, :start_date
```

If you do not have the columns in your database, you will need that.

`attr_accessible` allows parameters in a mass association.

`attr_accessor` sets a getter and a setter.

If you have those columns you could try prepending `self.`.

Comment: When I do this, it saves, but it causes another problem.  On events#show, I get the error `@event.start_date` is nil.  In the database, the date is there, and when I remove show automatically works again.

Comment: so i think your problem is related to the another answer here, try to parse the date before saving it.